# Whats going wrong with my IF statement and Is Numeric

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, isnumeric

The following code reveals a gap in my understanding. Can someone please tell me what it is and how to fix the code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NumberToGuess, Answer As Integer
    NumberToGuess = InputBox("Enter a Secret Number Between 1 and 20!")
    While Answer <> NumberToGuess
        Answer = InputBox("Please enter your guess")
        If IsNumeric(Answer) = False Then MsgBox("That ain't no number")
        If Answer > NumberToGuess Then MsgBox("Too high thicko. Try Again")
        If Answer < NumberToGuess Then MsgBox("Too Low chump. Try Again")
    End While
    MsgBox("Well done you guessed the right number")
End Sub
```

Comment: guessing here since my VB.Net is ancient. You are using Answer <> NumberToGuess before "Answer" has a value.

Comment: If you add the error message perhaps is more clear what you are asking

Comment: This question reveals a gap in my understanding of the point of this question. Just throwing in some code without naming a specific problem, desired behaviour etc. Probably https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for these sort of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems in this question and your question is vague about which one you are talking about. So I'll list all of them here.

1. You declare both `NumberToGuess` and `Answer` as Integer and assign it the result of an `InputBox`. But `InputBox` can return anything (number or alpha). And it will error out as soon as you try to assign the user's input to `NumberToGuess`. And that's before you check whether it is number or not.
2. If you have `OPTION STRICT ON` it will show you compilation error *"Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Integer'".* Keeping `OPTION STRICT ON` is a good practice in general and helps avoid innocent looking mistakes. e.g. Here you are assigning `String` type to `Integer`variable, which it doesn't allow.
3. You have used a `While` loop with `InputBox`. There is no way for user to cancel out of the game unless they give the correct answer. The Cancel button of InputBox won't work.
4. All your `If` conditions will be evaluated irrespective of previous one. I assume you want only one of the Message Boxes to be shown at a time. So you may want to make use of `ElseIf` too.

To fix the problems, here we go:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NumberToGuess As String    '<-- declare as string because we will hold the result of InputBox in it.
    Dim Answer As String = ""      '<-- declare as string because we will hold the result of InputBox in it.

    NumberToGuess = InputBox("Enter a Secret Number Between 1 and 20!")
    While Answer <> NumberToGuess
        Answer = InputBox("Please enter your guess")
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Answer) Then Exit While '<-- if user pressed cancel button in InputBox.
        If Not IsNumeric(Answer) Then
            MsgBox("That ain't no number")
        ElseIf CInt(Answer) > CInt(NumberToGuess) Then
            MsgBox("Too high thicko. Try Again")
        ElseIf CInt(Answer) < CInt(NumberToGuess) Then
            MsgBox("Too Low chump. Try Again")
        Else
            ' neither less nor more. so this is the correct answer.
            MsgBox("Well done you guessed the right number")
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

The above code however is a big annoyance because a `MessageBox`, then `InputBox, then`MessageBox`, then`InputBox...
To fix this, you can show the message in the `InputBox` itself.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NumberToGuess As String    '<-- declare as string because we will hold the result of InputBox in it.
    Dim Answer As String = ""      '<-- replace with whatever answer you are expecting.
    Dim Message As String = "Please enter your guess"

    NumberToGuess = InputBox("Enter a Secret Number Between 1 and 20!")
    While Answer <> NumberToGuess
        Answer = InputBox(Message)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Answer) Then Exit While '<-- if user pressed cancel button in InputBox.
        If Not IsNumeric(Answer) Then
            Message = "That ain't no number"
        ElseIf CInt(Answer) > CInt(NumberToGuess) Then
            Message = "Too high thicko. Try Again"
        ElseIf CInt(Answer) < CInt(NumberToGuess) Then
            Message = "Too Low chump. Try Again"
        Else
            ' neither less nor more. so this is the correct answer.
            MsgBox("Well done you guessed the right number")
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Your solution is elegant and addresses all the flaws in my understanding. I much prefer the combination of error message and input box rather than one after the other

Answer (score 1):

it's no big deal - you just missed some `else` ;)

```
private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NumberToGuess, Answer As Integer
    NumberToGuess = InputBox("Enter a Secret Number Between 1 and 20!")
    While Answer <> NumberToGuess
        Answer = InputBox("Please enter your guess")
        If IsNumeric(Answer) = False Then MsgBox("That ain't no number")
        Else
            If Answer > NumberToGuess Then MsgBox("Too high thicko. Try Again")
            If Answer < NumberToGuess Then MsgBox("Too Low chump. Try Again")
        End If
    End While
    MsgBox("Well done you guessed the right number")

End Sub
```

The problem is that if you just write it like this the first condition is checked - if you don't input a number the message is shown and your next condition is checked - you obvious only want those to be checked if it is a number. So wrap it inside an `Else` Block

BTW: I don't think the missing value for `Answer` is an issue but I cannot check right now (My MonoDevelop on my Linux Distro has some issues with VB.net :( - debug your code to find out if it is please)

Comment: Thank you very much for such a prompt reply.  I have been trying to play with an Else and ElseIF statement but without success. Your clear explanation helps me understand why the former is needed. However, when I make your adjustments, VB shows me a syntax error. The Else statement and the End IF statement are underlined in a blue squiggly line. Do you know why? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the return value of the [InputBox function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w(v=vs.90).aspx).
It returns a string and you try to assign it to an integer variable.
This forces the VB compiler to execute an implicit conversion from a string to an integer and, until you type valid numbers it works, but if you leave your inputbox empty, the implicit conversion fails and raises an `InvalidCastException`.

If you compile your code with [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) this will be caught during the build.
Without it your program crashes at the assignment.
The same problem is present in the assignement of NumberToGuess

```
Dim NumberToGuess, Answer As Integer
While True
    Dim input = InputBox("Enter a Secret Number Between 1 and 20!")
    if IsNumeric(input) Then
        NumberToGuess = Convert.ToInt32(input)
        Exit While
    Else
        MsgBox("Not a valid number")
    End If
End While    
While Answer <> NumberToGuess
    Dim result = InputBox("Please enter your guess")
    If IsNumeric(result) = False Then 
       MsgBox("That ain't no number")
    Else
       Answer = Convert.ToInt32(result)
       If Answer > NumberToGuess Then MsgBox("Too high thicko. Try Again")
       If Answer < NumberToGuess Then MsgBox("Too Low chump. Try Again")
    End If
End While
MsgBox("Well done you guessed the right number")
```

I should also add that the answer from [Mr Carsten Konig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76051/carsten-k%C3%B6nig) is rightly pointing to an error in your logical code flow.

Comment: it unconditionally prints `Well done you guessed the right number` all times since it is out side the while

Comment: It never exits the loop if you don't type the correct number.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much Steve. Its amazing how a simple program can teach you so much. I really appreciate your help. Ditto everyone else who posted such useful comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 Dim NumberToGuess, Answer As Integer
        NumberToGuess = InputBox("Enter a Secret Number Between 1 and 20!")
        While Answer <> NumberToGuess
            Answer = InputBox("Please enter your guess")
            If IsNumeric(Answer) = False Then
                MsgBox("That ain't no number")
            Else
                Select Case Answer < NumberToGuess
                    Case True
                        MsgBox("Too Low chump. Try Again")
                    Case False
                        MsgBox("Too high thicko. Try Again")
                    Case Else
                        MsgBox("Well done you guessed the right number")
                End Select
            End If
        End While
```